# Can I say "I have been dedicated my work"?

Tags: word-usage, present-perfect, phrases

I know "I am dedicated to my work" is a correct sentence.

Then, in order to express for a long time and imply that it is about to change something, can I say "I have been dedicated my work for 30 years"? 
Or is there any other appropriate sentence?

I want to focus on "I did it for a long time, until now."

My sentence:

> I have been dedicated my work for 30 years. But now I think I should quit my job and spend my time with myself.

Comment: No, you can't just drop the preposition *to*.  It doesn't change the meaning, it's just incorrect.

Comment: Please let me ask. you said It doesn't change the meaning. Is these sentece exact same meaning, "I am dedicated to my work"and"I have been dedicated to my work" ?

Comment: @stangdon was talking about the preposition "to" in relation with your whole question. It's beyond my capacity to explain you all the differences between those phrases, maybe he can help, but the first indicates that you are dedicated to your work at the present, at this moment but it does not inform about what you have done in the past. The second one implies that you have maintained the dedication during some period of time (30 years).

Answer (score 2):

You cannot drop the word "to". This sentence is ok:

> I have been dedicated **to** my work for 30 years. But now I think I should quit my job and spend my time with myself.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, my apologies because I tried to edit your question fixing some minor details and typos and including the particle "to" in your title and main text. I think that the relevant part in your question is about the use of **have been dedicated** and not about the specific presence of **to** or not. My suggested edit was correctly rejected.

The correct use, as stated in comments and a previous answer, includes that "to". It's important. I'm not being ironic.

Let me suggest you some equivalents

> **I've been working hard for years** and now is time to take a good rest
>
> **I've spent my adulthood working hard** and it's time to just enjoy 
>   live/my family/my kids/surfing

And last but not least, using the correct form

> **I've been dedicated to** my work and now it's time to left those worries
>   behind

Re-answering your question in the comments, let me paste the definition of the **present perfect simple** [to have + participle] form from the [Cambridge Dictionary](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/grammar/british-grammar/present/present-perfect-simple-i-have-worked)

> We use the present perfect simple to refer to events in the past but
>   which connect to the present.